# LinqPad error with Rx.NET Observable

Tags: system.reactive, linqpad

I'm trying to run Rx.NET inside LinqPad. I added the Rx.NET DLLs as you see in the picture.

The error that I'm seeing is

> CS0103 The name 'Observable' does not exist in the current context.

How can I fix this error?

[image]

Comment: There's a NuGet package available of Rx.NET too, it's called `System.Reactive`. It might be easier to use that one in LinqPad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure you have added the required namespaces in the "Additional Namespace Imports" tab (accessible via Ctrl-Shift-M).

For `Observable` you need `System.Reactive.Linq`.